# How to tacacs enable in python for checkpoint firewalls

Tags: python, networking, automation, syntax-error, netmiko

I am trying to work on a python script that logs onto a firewall, moves into TACP-15 and enters the relevant password.  After which it runs a command.

Problem is the script is getting stuck at the password prompt after running: tacacs_enable TACP-15.

```
The relevant part of code is this: 

output = net_connect.send_command('lock database override')
print(output)

output = net_connect.send_command('tacacs_enable TACP-15')
print(output)

output = net_connect.send_command(expert_password)
print(output)

output = net_connect.send_command('show route')
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would check if your OS is a supported [platform](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/develop/PLATFORMS.md). If it is supported most likely the "enable" part is handled by netmiko and you can just use the `enable()` function.

Otherwise you will find in the examples code snippets how to deal with a prombt.

- [handling-commands-that-prompt-timing](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/develop/EXAMPLES.md#handling-commands-that-prompt-timing)
- [handling-commands-that-prompt-expect_string](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/develop/EXAMPLES.md#handling-commands-that-prompt-expect_string)

Here an example:

```py
output = net_connect.send_command(
    command_string="tacacs_enable TACP-15",
    expect_string=r"Password",
    strip_prompt=False,
    strip_command=False
)
print(output)

# Now you can probably sending a normal `send_command` or again specify the expect_string
output = net_connect.send_command(
    command_string=expert_password,
    expect_string=r"#",
    strip_prompt=False,
    strip_command=False
)
print(output)
```

Comment: Hi sir thanks for your answer but still getting the same issue

Comment: Did you change the expect_string for your use case?

Comment: yes I am trying to enter TACP-15 but its not taking the enable password

Comment: How does the output look after the command "tacacs_enable TACP-15" if you connect directly by SSH?

Comment: If I do that manually it connects I am just unable to enter TACP-15 using python

Comment: I want to run show asset all command on checkpoint firewalls

Comment: So the command "tacacs_enable TACP-15" does not return any prompt? not asking for a password? Did you try the second example with timing?

Comment: yes I did try it

Comment: You still did not tell if the command gives any prompt. Without any information, it is not possible to give you more advances.

Comment: Basically after I enter Tacacs_enable TACP-15 command it gives the enable password prompt but after that it gets stuck The program does not run futher